# yocto does not merge my patches

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Hi I am adding patches on my bb file and yocto does apply the patches however is not merging them just applying the changes.  How can I get bitbake to apply the patches?  I know in recipes-kernel my patches get merged but not anywhere else?

Comment: There is not enough information here - at least show the bb file. Also 'merge' does not really make sense here, what exactly is the problem you see?

Comment: Looks like your problem is described and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52423683/apply-and-commit-a-patch-from-bitbake-recipe

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, there's no such thing as patch merging. Patches are applied right after unpacking the source.

To have a patch applied on your recipe, be sure to have the patch file in a subfolder of the recipe. This subfolder name must either be "files" or the package name.

Then you need to have it in SRC_URI (like [here](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#using-a-quilt-workflow)).

Without more information, I can't go into details

Answer (score 0):

To apply a patch to our recipe,you have to create a ".bbappend" file for the recipe.Make sure that the name and version of *.bbappend is same as* .bb file.

In .bbappend file add,

`FILESEXTAPATCH = "path_to_your_patch_directory"`

`SRC_URI += "patch_name.patch"`

The next time you run Bitbake to build your recipe, Bitbake will detect the change, fetches and apply the patch before building.

The information you gave is not enough. So if possible show .bb or .bbappend file.

Comment: Hi here is what I have
SRC_URI += "file://0001-just-a-test.patch"
and I have a files/0001-just-a-test.patch
The patch does apply but it does not check it in.  If I do git log I do not see the history.  If I add patches to kernel I can do git log and see the history

Comment: @GabrielPadilla when you apply patch in a git repository, only the changes are reflected,if you want a entry in git log you have to explicitly do git commit after applying patches. Please go through [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply). In case of kernel, you need to check kernel recipe/classes files. I have not checked but there might be git commit written in its recipe/classes, which is the reason why you can see its entry in git log.