# Apply and commit a patch from bitbake recipe

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded, texas-instruments

I am observing that the yocto build system is just applying my patch instead of applying and committing the patch on the cloned git repo.

Original bitbake (**u-boot-ti-staging_2018.01.bb**) file.

```
require u-boot-ti.inc

PR = "r19"

BRANCH = "ti-u-boot-2018.01"

SRCREV = "8b2f1df4b55bc0797399a21d42ac191d44f99227"
```

Modified bitbake file, added **SRC_URI** to the file.

```
require u-boot-ti.inc

PR = "r19"

BRANCH = "ti-u-boot-2018.01"

SRCREV = "8b2f1df4b55bc0797399a21d42ac191d44f99227"

SRC_URI += "file://0001-Stopping-DHCP-server-giving-new-serverip.patch \
        "
```

I have added a patch file under files directory. The content of the patch (**0001-Stopping-DHCP-server-giving-new-serverip.patch**) file is as follows.

```
From cf97b6053f00afd496d01a892599cd8f4b254087 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: Sunny Shukla <sunny.shukla@xyz.com>
Date: Wed, 19 Sep 2018 18:23:49 +0530
Subject: [PATCH] Stopping DHCP server giving new serverip

Added CONFIG_BOOTP_SERVERIP in the config file, this
stops the DHCP server gives new "serverip" address and 
overrides the current one.
---
 include/configs/am335x_evm.h | 2 ++
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)

diff --git a/include/configs/am335x_evm.h b/include/configs/am335x_evm.h
index 01f0277..4b3047d 100644
--- a/include/configs/am335x_evm.h
+++ b/include/configs/am335x_evm.h
@@ -18,6 +18,8 @@

 #include <configs/ti_am335x_common.h>

+#define CONFIG_BOOTP_SERVERIP
+
 #ifndef CONFIG_SPL_BUILD
 # define CONFIG_TIMESTAMP
 #endif
-- 
2.7.4
```

The patch is applying like someone is executing a "**git apply 0001-Stopping-DHCP-server-giving-new-serverip.patch**" command on top of the cloned git repo as show below. But rather I want that the patch must be applied like someone is executing a "**git am 0001-Stopping-DHCP-server-giving-new-serverip.patch**" command on top of the cloned git repo.

**git status**

```
On branch ti-u-boot-2018.01
Your branch is behind 'origin/ti-u-boot-2018.01' by 23 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   include/configs/am335x_evm.h

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I want this patch to be applied and committed on top of the cloned git repo. How to achieve that under a bitbake file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yocto by default uses `quilt` when no patch tool is specified. You can specify

```
PATCHTOOL = "git"
```

in your recipe, so that Yocto automatically applies it using "git am".

See [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.0.1/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-PATCHTOOL) for more details.

NOTE: This functionality will start adding an extra line to the patch's description like "**%%original patch: 0001-Stopping-DHCP-server-giving-new-serverip.patch**" while applying the patch. To get rid of it, comment the below line under "**oe-core/meta/lib/oe/patch.py**" file.

https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/lib/oe/patch.py#n519

Comment: No did nothing like "git am" it is still doing "git apply". I changed the PATCHTOOL = "git" under do_patch_prepend() function.

Comment: The scope of the variable will be lost and destroyed after `prepend`. So you need to define outside i.e something like `SRC_URI`

Comment: Can you please explain how to do that, am very novice to yocto.

Comment: it worked. I just put the  PATCHTOOL = "git" above SRC_URI and it worked like a champ. Thanks

Comment: One more thing, this git am is adding an extra line to my patch description like this "%%original patch: 0001-Stopping-DHCP-server-giving-new-serverip.patch" is there any way to get rid of it apart from commenting the line under oe-core/meta/lib/oe/patch.py file !

Comment: Probably this line : https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/lib/oe/patch.py#n519.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180707/discussion-between-sunny-shukla-and-parthiban).

Comment: Yes, please let me know your pending and questions in chat